# Meteor Semantic UI react: Modifying user account information

Tags: meteor, settings, account, semantic-ui-react, meteor-accounts

In creating a user settings page, I wanted display current user account email and password and give the user the ability to change both.

I read up on https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#displaying-user-data, but I'm still confused about how the data is handled.

Would somebody be able to point me in the right direction? Attached below is a code snippet of how our sign-up page handles the data.

```
      /** Handle Signup submission. Create user account and a profile entry, then redirect to the home page. */
  submit = () => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    Accounts.createUser({ email, username: email, password }, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        this.setState({ error: err.reason });
      } else {
        this.setState({ error: '', redirectToReferer: true });
      }
    });
```

}

Comment: The given code only shows how a user is signed up but not how the user is displayed on the settings page. Can you please show the code that intends to display the user account settings?

Comment: For methods that change user settings see the docs: https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-changePassword
https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-addEmail